# how can I make symfony see my new relations between tables?

Tags: php, orm, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I am using symfony 1.4 for a project (already started), now I am changing some stuffs and I get an error of relations when I query for some info between two tables, one already exist and the other one is a new one, that should have a foreign key pointing to the first table.

and I get an error message like this

```
exception 'Doctrine_Table_Exception' with message 'Unknown relation alias ' in /var/www/testorange/symfony/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Relation/Parser.php:237 

Stack trace: #0 /var/www/testorange/symfony/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Relation/Parser.php(235): Doctrine_Relation_Parser->getRelation('', false)
```

...

and many errors more.

So, I think its because my tables have no the proper relations yet on my definition in symfony (they are already related on my DB).

I added this line to my schema.yml then [UPDATED]

```
 OhrmTrainningSubmit:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: ohrm_trainning_submit
  columns:
    id_trainning_submit:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    trainning:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    trainning_detail:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    answer:
      type: string(250)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    state:
      type: integer(1)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '0'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    user:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    OhrmUser:
      local: user
      foreign: emp_number
      type: many
    OhrmTrainning:
      local: trainning
      foreign: id_trainning
      type: many
```

this is the definition for OhrmUser

```
OhrmUser:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: ohrm_user
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    user_role_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    emp_number:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    user_name:
      type: string(40)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    user_password:
      type: string(40)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    deleted:
      type: integer(1)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '0'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    status:
      type: integer(1)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '1'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    date_entered:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    date_modified:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    modified_user_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    created_by:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    HsHrEmployee:
      local: emp_number
      foreign: emp_number
      type: one
    OhrmUserRole:
      local: user_role_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    HsHrMailnotifications:
      local: id
      foreign: user_id
      type: many
    OhrmLeaveAdjustment:
      local: id
      foreign: created_by_id
      type: many
    OhrmLeaveComment:
      local: id
      foreign: created_by_id
      type: many
    OhrmLeaveEntitlement:
      local: id
      foreign: created_by_id
      type: many
    OhrmLeaveRequestComment:
      local: id
      foreign: created_by_id
      type: many
    OhrmTimesheetActionLog:
      local: id
      foreign: performed_by
      type: many
```

On the table where I wanna make the reference, the field that will make the reference is "user" to the table "OhrmUser" to the field emp_number (I think should be correct this way), the problem is that still the same error, does anybody have idea of this? something else I should do?

After I added that I run this

```
php symfony cc
php symfony doctrine:build-model
php symfony orangehrm:publish-assets
php symfony cc
```

The query

```
try{
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
 ->select('*')
->from('OhrmTrainningSubmit TS')
->innerJoin('TS.OhrmUser U')
->addWhere("TS.trainning = $training")
->andWhere("TS.user = $employee");
$result = $q->execute();
    return $result;
}catch(Exception $e){
    print_r ($e->getMessage());
    return null;
}
```

I can access to the data of OhrmTrainningSubmit only, but when I try to access to a field of User I get internal error.

I get the error at this code

```
foreach ($detail as $det){
    echo $det['answer']; // This is printed with no problem
    //echo $det['user_name']; <-- this one comes from the table OhrmUser, I get server error with this one
}
```

where $detail is the variable with the return value of the query.

When I make

```
->select('TS.*, U.*')
```

I get other error, that says

> Unknown property emp_number

any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code which is generating the query and the whole schema for the table where you added the relation?

Comment: Thanks, I added some edition to my post, could you check it please?

Comment: Please post the code where you try to access the fields of `OhrmUser`. You can also use `select('TS.*, U.*)` to avoid lazy loading of the user fields.

Comment: Thanks! I will try , I didnt know about the lazy mode. I wrote the code with the error.

Comment: sorry for ask so much, now with selecting both tables I get a new error, unknow property emp_number, its my foreign key.. please check my update

Comment: See my edited answer below for proper use of joined properties. Does this solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. In your schema make sure you have the correct indentation near relations:

   ```
     autoincrement: false
   relations:
     OhrmUser:
       local: user
       foreign: emp_number
       type: many
   ```
2. The query should look like this:

   ```
   $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
       ->from('TrainningSubmit T')
       ->innerJoin('T.OhrmUser U')
       ->where('T.id_trainning = ?', $id);
   ```

When you specify the join in doctrine you must tell the ORM where does the relation come from - thus `T.OhrmUser U` instead of `OhrmUser U`. This tells doctrine that you are using the `OhrmUser` relation from the `T` model.

What is more you used `->where()` twice which is wrong because the second where overwrites the first one. You should use `->andWhere()` or `->orWhere()` if you want to add more than one `where` condition. Nevertheless when dealing with named relations in doctrine you don't have to tell doctrine explicitly on what columns it should make the join - it already knows that thanks to the schema file.

What is more, if you need to extend the condition of the join you can do that easily using `WITH`, e.g.

```
 ->join('T.OhrmUser U WITH U.name LIKE ?', 'Michal')
```

will translate to:

```
 JOIN OhrmUser U ON U.emp_number = T.user AND U.name LIKE 'Michal'
```

**EDIT**

To retrieve data from the object use:

```
//if you return a plain array as a result of the query:
echo $det['answer'];
echo $det['OhrmUser']['user_name'];

//if you return an array of objects:
echo $det->getAnswer();
echo $det->getOhrmUser()->getUserName();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! its a nice explanation, I did what you said but I kept getting the same errors, the query goes fine, but when I try to access to the field of the joined table I get an error 500 and nothing works anymore.. any idea what could be?? I did something like this     $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
     ->select('*')
    ->from('OhrmTrainningSubmit TS')
    ->innerJoin('TS.OhrmUser U')
    ->addWhere("TS.trainning = $training")
    ->addWhere("TS.user = $employee");
    $result = $q->execute();

Comment: How do you access the fields of the joined table? (you can an edit to your post) Also in the `where` part you should rather use parameters: `where('TS.training = ?', $training)` instead of `where("TS.training = $training")`

Comment: Thanks! could you please check my update? I kept having the same error, I can access to the info of my first table, but not the info of the joined table

Comment: just one more question, if I want to make another join can i still use "Join" or something like addJoin ?

Comment: You can add additional joins just with the `join()` function. Only with `where()` it won't work.